# Did the movie show or hinted at who vandalized Dustin's car with the obscene drawing?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, hesher

Who vandalized Dustin's car with the obscene drawing?

[image: Screencap of said scene]]

Was it TJ or was it [Hesher?](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hesher_%28film%29) I would like to know more about the characters of TJ and/or Hesher based on that event in the film.

I was wondering if TJ deserved Dustin's rage or if this was actually Hesher's first "act of revenge" to Dustin for what happened to TJ. If it was the former, then we'll know that TJ is actually capable of revenge (but not "Hesher level"), and might deserve Dustin's rage after all. If it was the latter, then it means Hesher saw this act of bullying (the text in the obscene drawing was what Dustin said to TJ) and the second act of bullying, and did nothing to intervene at both occasions, but did the "act of revenge" for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The film hints at the perpetrator in the scene where Hesher is standing outside the window sniffing a marker:

[image]

He throws the marker at TJ, but then the teacher takes it away.

Comment: I didn't notice that it was hinting at that. I thought it was just Hesher "being Hesher". Thanks for mentioning it.